# Invoke-Webrequest gets 401 on POST but not on GET with Basic Auth

Tags: powershell, web-applications, invoke-webrequest

I have a dev site with Basic Auth enabled. I am get to GET a page using the following to add basic auth to the headers:

```
$creds = "$($BASIC_AUTH_USER):$($BASIC_AUTH_PASS)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($creds))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
$headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}

$login = Invoke-WebRequest $url -SessionVariable session -UseBasicParsing -Headers $headers
```

But I am unable to post to the same URL:

```
$fields = @{ Email = $SITE_USER; Password = $SITE_PASS; }
$login = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -WebSession $session -Body $fields -UseBasicParsing -Headers $headers
```

I get a 401 Unauthorized back. Everything works fine if I disable basic auth on the site. So I know it isn't a server issue. I am able to POST using my browser.

Edit: So it seems basic auth is working correctly when I debug on the server. But my server returns a redirect, which is then causing Invoke-Webrequest to interpret that as a 401.

Any idea on why this may not be working?

Comment: Isn't 401 unauthorized which means you don't have permission to POST?

Comment: I am able to post to this site from the browser. If I disable basic auth on the site, then the script works. So yes i believe I do have permission to post.

Answer (score 3):

You get this behaviour because of the redirect; when making this additional request to the redirect location the authorization header doesn't get included.

For this reason **PowerShell 6.0.0** added the **PreserveAuthorizationOnRedirect** parameter.

> Indicates the cmdlet should preserve the Authorization header, when present, across redirections.
>   By default, the cmdlet strips the Authorization header before redirecting. Specifying this parameter disables this logic for cases where the header needs to be sent to the redirection location.

[Invoke-WebRequest reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6)

---

As an **alternative**, if you are not on PowerShell 6, you can work around it via a more lowlevel script using `System.Net.WebRequest` wich defines a property **`AllowAutoRedirect`** that can be set to `False` in order to skip the redirect after a successful POST, avoiding the 401 error.

Notice that you have to take care of things like the data/body formatting (json, form-urlencoded, ...) and http-headers yourself.

The script will look like here below.
Notice the line with `AllowAutoRedirect = $false`.

```
$creds = "$($BASIC_AUTH_USER):$($BASIC_AUTH_PASS)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($creds))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$url = "http://your.url"
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::CreateHttp($url);   
$request.Method = "post"
$request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $basicAuthValue)
$request.AllowAutoRedirect = $false

$body = "your formatted data goes here"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body);
$stream = $request.GetRequestStream()
$stream.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length);
$stream.Close();

$request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

It most likely has to do with the redirect as pfx said, you could also do a MaximumRedirection of 0 and catch the error. This way you can get the redirected url and try again.